# stop a form submit (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to stop a submit form with Javascript/jQuery, with a:

```
$('form#checkRepair').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

---

this work in all browsers, but not in Internet Explorer  (version 8).
In Internet Explorer version 9, works.

does anyone know what the problem is?

### I'm use a jQuery version 1.6.4.

```
$('form#checkRepair').submit(function() {
    var nrObra = $('#nrObra').val();
    var nrDocCliente = $('#nrDocCliente').val();

    if((nrObra == '' || nrObra == 'Número de Reparação') 
        && (nrDocCliente == '' || nrDocCliente  == 'Doc. Cliente')) {
        $('form#checkRepair .error').show();
        return false;
    }

    $('form#checkRepair .error').hide();

    var nrJoja = $('#nrLoja').val();

    $(this).hide();
    $('#loader').show();

    var url = "http://uri.com";

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        if(typeof data.error != 'undefined') {
            $('#status_repair_error div').html('<h1>Ocorreu um Erro</h1>' + data.error);
            $('#status_repair_error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#status_repair').hide();
        } else {            
            $('#status_repair #repair-number span').text(data.repair.SAT_OBRANR);
            $('#status_repair #repair-state span').text(data.repair.situacao);
            $('#status_repair #repair-reason span').text(data.repair.motivo);
            $('#status_repair #product-name span').text(data.repair.produto);
            $('#status_repair #product-model span').text(data.repair.modelo);
            $('#status_repair #product-mark span').text(data.repair.marca);
            $('#status_repair #product-nrSerie span').text(data.repair.NSerieE);
            $('#status_repair #date-repair span').text(data.repair.dt_Pronta);
            $('#status_repair #date-lifting span').text(data.repair.dt_Entrega);
            $('#status_repair #client-name span').text(data.repair.cliente.nome);

            $("#status_repair li").each(function(index) {
                var text = $(this).children("span").text();
                if(text == '')
                    $(this).hide();
            });

            $('#nrObra').val('');
            $('#nrDocCliente').val('');
            $('#nrLoja').val('');
        }

        $.colorbox({
            inline:true, innerWidth:"960px", open: true, href: "#status_repair_container",
            onClosed:function(){ 
                $('form#checkRepair').show();
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#status_repair_error').hide();
                $('#status_repair').show();
            }
        });
    }, 'jsonp');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was in webform libary

Comment: You should explain exactly what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `preventDefault()` method?

```
$('form#checkRepair').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I had already tried that way, but does not work in IE8.

`$('form#checkRepair').submit(function(e) {
  var nrObra = $('#nrObra').val();
  var nrDocCliente = $('#nrDocCliente').val();
  
  if((nrObra == '' || nrObra == 'Número de Reparação') 
   && (nrDocCliente == '' || nrDocCliente  == 'Doc. Cliente')) {
   $('form#checkRepair .error').show();
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }

                // ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("form#checkRepair").submit(function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: I had already tried that way, but does not work in IE8.

`$('form#checkRepair').submit(function(e) {
  var nrObra = $('#nrObra').val();
  var nrDocCliente = $('#nrDocCliente').val();
  
  if((nrObra == '' || nrObra == 'Número de Reparação') 
   && (nrDocCliente == '' || nrDocCliente  == 'Doc. Cliente')) {
   $('form#checkRepair .error').show();
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }

                // ...`

Comment: When you use this function, it automatically transforms the normal form into an ajax form, so when you submit, all it needs is a classic <input type=submit> call for the ajax form to process.  Depending on how you are submitting the form, are you using javascript or are you using a classic submit button?  A classic submit button should work.

Comment: the function is called when I click a button (type=submit). that's why I think damage does not work. `<input type="submit" name="check" id="check" value="Procurar" class="button" />`

Comment: there should be no triggers on the submit button, just leave it as is. Make sure the .submit() code initializes and it transforms the existing form into an ajax one, no further events need to be called on the submit button besides it doing a normal submit as it is supposed to.